# How does LINQ sort in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I learn C# and try to understand how does LINQ work?

```
int[] arr = {5,1,9,4,6,2,8,3,7};
var arr2 = from i in arr
           orderby i
           select i;
```

How does the LINQ sort the array and what is running time?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2: *This method compares keys by using the default comparer [`Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.default?view=netframework-4.7.2).*

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderBy.cs

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually sort the array, but returns a new enumerable. The sorting algorithm used by linq2objects is Quicksort which has a time complexity of *O(n log n)*

Answer (score 0):

It sorts "Ascending" by default, from the example:

```
int[] arr = { 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 2, 8, 3, 7};
var var1 = from i in arr
orderby i //ascending
select i;
```

If you want to do it descending:

```
int[] arr = { 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 2, 8, 3, 7};
var var1 = from i in arr
orderby i descending
select i;
```

Hope it helped you.